# pythonanywhere: - img src not showing picture

Tags: image, pythonanywhere

My page: https://bbqbailey.pythonanywhere.com/ is not showing correctly - image is missing.

**I see the picture if I do this from a computer that is logged into pythonanywhere.**

**I do not see it on any other computer!**

So I'm expecting that some sort of permissions problem is going on, but the "ls -al" in console shows everything with 644 permission.

The text is displayed correctly, as is the 'alt' info, but the actual image isn't shown.

I put the image at: /home/mysite/learningFlask/SarahJustinEngaged.jpg, and I can see it as stated above from a computer logged into pythonanywhere, but no other computers can see it if not logged in.

I don't see anything from any computer if I use the "

What am I missing????? Help! We're wanting to show this to family and friends now!!!

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>Sarah and Justin are Engaged!</h1> 
 <img src="https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/bbqbailey/files/home/bbqbailey/mysite/learningFlask/SarahJustinEngaged.jpg" alt="Sarah and Justin are Engaged!" width="567" height="500"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You're using a file URL that is only valid when you are logged in to PythonAnywhere, since we do not expose all of your files to everyone on the internet. To serve files, use a static files mapping. Serach for "static files" in our help pages to find out how to use and debug them.

Answer (score 0):

actually Django support consept of static file so create a folder name static inside your project folder store all image on that

`{%load static%} <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <h1>Sarah and Justin are Engaged!</h1> <img src="{% static 'SarahJustinEngaged.jpg' %}" alt="Sarah and Justin are Engaged!" width="567" height="500"> </body> </html>`